# Application Resolution Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, resolution

This is something that I have been skipping and leaving till the end because I can't seem to find the answer and ive looked for so long.

I have a an application inside a Window, and I have built the Application to my screens resolution which is 1600 x 900. If I run the application on a screen with a resolution of 1024 x 768 my whole interface will not scale down.

**Example.**

[image]

Now I know alot of you will be thinking to add Dockpanels etc ... But I have tried to do this. When you change the Resolutions it doesn't work it just fixes the object to one place.

**What I want to happen.**

[image]

If any of you know the solution to this annoying problem, please let me know.

*I dont know much about resolutions, only what I have done hours of research on.*

**EDIT1**

Here is some of my XAML:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" LastChildFill="False" Margin="380,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgFake" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="236" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF474747" BorderBrush="#FFBDBDBD" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" CanUserResizeRows="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Background="#FFEEFAFF" RowBackground="#FFEEFAFF" RowHeaderWidth="0" RowHeight="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="792" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="16" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="dgFake_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FFF}" Header="FFF" Visibility="Hidden" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EEE}" Header="EEE" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GGG}" Header="GGG" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CCC}" Header="CCC" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BBB}" Header="BBB" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AAA}" Header="AAA" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DDD}" Header="DDD" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

<Label x:Name="lblView" Content="Select View ..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF474747"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbViews" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162" Text="Select ..." SelectionChanged="cmbView">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Company" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Employee" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you please post the xaml of the things that are not re-sizing, e.e.g DataGrid, panel holding the "Home" etc labels at the top?

Comment: @AlSki Everything doesn't resize but i posted my Datagrid and a combobox for example in edit.

Comment: Yep, Everything is fixed with Heights and Margins. As @Sheridan suggested you have laid everything out as we used to do in WinForms. This is one big disadvantage of using the designer. Try the example I've posted and see if you can apply the same layout to your window. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have basically designed your WPF application as if it were a WinForms application, setting exact `Height` and `Width` values on your UI elements. That is *not* how we layout UI elements in WPF. If you *did* do that, then you are correct that putting them in a `DockPanel` will not fix your problem.

In WPF, we generally use `Grid` elements to make full use of the available space provided to them. Setting a `Grid.ColumnDefinition.Width` to `Auto` and another to `*` will fill *all of the available width:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- Just big enough for content -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />    <!-- Fills all remaining space -->
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="I'm in the right cell" />
```

That's just one example of many... Please read through the [Introduction to WPF Layout](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) page from the WPF Tutorial.net website for more information.

Comment: I do agree with this answer, also use margin to position your control will cost your flexibility to adjust to resolution. should avoid it.

Comment: @Sheridan After taking a brief look at the URL, Every object e.g Textbox has its own Cell in a Grid, from there you set that object with a Width of either Auto or *. The Auto will Automatically fit to the size of the object, and the * will fill the available space left. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Johnny So how do I position object in a cell. Do I just use alignment?

Comment: @Ben, yes you are on the right track. I've edited my answer to show you how to set an element into the cell using the `Grid.Column` Attached property. Also note the `Grid.Row`, `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` Attached Properties.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for the answer, I will fix my interface now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is actually quite easy to solve, you simply NEVER use a fixed size for anything. All your panels have to be sized relative to something.

Changing the resolution of a screen is literally the same as changing the size of your window. If it works with a `Window.Size` of 1024x768 it will work at a 1024x768 resolution.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="384" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Pretend I'm a logo -->
    <Border Height="23" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Blue" CornerRadius="5" Padding="3">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White">Logo</TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="About" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Home" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Help" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Settings" Margin="6"/>
    </WrapPanel>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  
             BorderThickness="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Example" Margin="6"/>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border >
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock>I'm a Data Grid</TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="3"/>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,3,0,0">            
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock>I'm a Data Grid</TextBlock>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The gradients are there so you can see its working when you resize.

Comment: Posted now, See if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the example, this worked perfectly and has given me a better insight into what i need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already designed to a fixed resolution then an easy hack is to wrap everything in a ViewBox and give the encapsulating child the same dimensions as the resolution you designed for. So if you designed for 1600 x 900 and your main window contained this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Big Text" FontSize="100" />
</Grid>
```

...then replace it with this:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid Width="1600" Height="900">
        <TextBlock Text="Big Text" FontSize="100" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Then make a mental note to do your UI design properly from day 1 next time.

Comment: This method you explained, are there disadvantages?

Comment: @Ben If the user changes the size of the window then everything will scale accordingly, and beyond a certain point the text will be too small to read. Also it doesn't seem possible to set TextOptions to do pixel-aligned rendering of fonts, so it's not possible to get rid of that very slight blurring of text that most WPF applications have by default.